# Schengen visa refused as a security and health threat

Tags: visa-refusals, turkey, pakistani-citizens, residency, schengen-visas

I am from Pakistan and I travelled to the Schengen area two times in 2015 on business. The visa was issued by the Embassy of Hungary.

When I applied again in 2017, for the same business trip, the Hungarian Embassy refused and give reason nunber 6.

> 6. One or more member state(s) consider you to be a threat to public policy, internal security, public health as defined in Article 2(19) of Regulation (EC) No 562/2006 (Schengen Borders Code) or the international relations of one or more of the member states).

After that, I travelled two times to Turkey and I also have Turkish temporary residence permit.

Can I apply to Italy for a Schengen tourist visa? Does the earlier reason for refusal have an affect on this application? If I wanted to apply for a transit visa would it be approved or refused?

Comment: You *can* apply, but without knowing what they refer to (and fixing the problem), you are extremely likely to get another visa refusal. Sounds like a great way to waste money.

Comment: This reason for refusal is usually not given lightly. *Some* intelligence agency thinks that they have information on you. Note that Turkish views on what constitutes extremism and EU views are quite different. Think back about your past (not only 2015, the data could be older) if there is reason why your activities could be misconstrued as extremism or if it has to be mistaken identity.

Comment: But during my both schegen visit i follow the rules . I Registered a company and pay tax's i don't know why this happen how they declare me threat . About turkish residence permit i got now in end of 2017 not before refusel of the visa's

Comment: It is then most likely a case of identity mismatch. Your first step should be to get the Hungarian consulate to reveal which member state objected your visa application. You will then have to contact the said state's authorities to solve the problem.

Comment: @tor-Einar janbjo thanks.  ok i will contact hungary embasy and ask detials or resolve the issue on my data